# Select orders which have the combination of product A and B

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying to figure out a query that will get a list of orders which will have the combination of product A and B, C and D , X and Y, etc. So I need a list that will show only orders that have the combinations specified. Something like the code bellow:

```
select order_id, product_name
from orders
where product in( A & B, C & D)
group by order_id
```

Comment: i update answer

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me interpret your question as wanting specific pairs of products.  If so, you can use `group by` and `having`.  Assuming that there are no duplicates in your data:

```
select o.order_id
from orders o 
group by o.order_id
having sum(case when o.product in ('A', 'B') then 1 else 0 end) = 2 or
       sum(case when o.product in ('C', 'D') then 1 else 0 end) = 2 or
       sum(case when o.product in ('X', 'Y') then 1 else 0 end) = 2;
```

If you want orders that have exactly *two* products and those pairs, then add the condition `count(*)` = 2.  Or, if you want to be abstruse, you can change the `else` to something like `else 10`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the SQL above worked fine, thank you ! I am just having some issues when adding non-aggregating fields to the SELECT that should not be in the GROUP BY statement. That is, I need to group by only order_id but I also need the 2 products contained in each order_id. Any idea ?

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull . . . If you have only two products, then use `min(product), max(product)`.

Answer (score 0):

if your table data like

```
| ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT |
|----------|--------------|---------|
|        1 |        xxx01 |     A、B |
|        2 |        xxx02 |     B、C |
|        3 |        xxx03 |     C、D |
|        4 |        xxx04 |     D、X |
|        5 |        xxx05 |     E、Z |
```

try this script:

```
select order_id,product_name ,product
from orders 
where product like ('%A%B%') 
or product like ('%C%D%')
```

---

if your table data like ;

```
| ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT |
|----------|--------------|---------|
|        1 |        xxx01 |       A |
|        1 |        xxx02 |       B |
|        2 |        xxx03 |       C |
|        2 |        xxx04 |       D |
|        3 |        xxx05 |       E |
```

try this script:

```
select order_id
from orders 
group by order_id having   
  count( case when product in ('A','B') then 1 else null end  ) > 1
  or 
  count( case when product in ('C','D') then 1 else null end  ) > 1
```

Comment: @JonathanLivingstonSeagull Why don't you post your table structure